# Find $\lim\limits_{X \rightarrow X_0} f(X)$ using an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument : $f(X) =3x+4y+z-2$ and $X_0 =(1,2,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

> Find $\lim\limits_{X \rightarrow X_0} f(X)$ and justify your answer with the  $\epsilon-\delta$ definition given $$f(X) =3x+4y+z-2$$ and $X_0 =(1,2,1)$

Here is the definition

> > Definition: we have the limit $L$ such that $$\lim\limits_{X \rightarrow X_0} f(X) = L$$ if $X_0$ is a limit point of $D_f$ and, for every  $\epsilon > 0 $, there is a $\delta >0 $ such that $$|f(X)-L| < \epsilon$$ for all $X$ in $D_f$ such that $$0<|X-X_0|<\delta$$

$\forall \epsilon>0$,
$$|f(X) - L| < \epsilon$$
$$=|f(x,y,z) - \lim\limits_{(x,y,z) \rightarrow (x_0,y_0,z_0)} f(x,y,z)|< \epsilon$$
$$=|(3x+4y+z-2) - (3x_{0} + 4y_{0} +z_{0} -2)| <\epsilon$$

$$=| 3(x-x_0) +4(y-y_0) +(z-z_0) | <\epsilon$$

Using triangle inequality
$$\leq 3|x-x_0| +4|y-y_0| +|z-z_0| <\epsilon$$
$$\leq 4|x-x_0| +4|y-y_0| +4|z-z_0| <\epsilon$$
$$ \leq 4|X -X_0| <\epsilon$$
$$ \implies |X -X_0| <\delta < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$$

.

Am I going in the right direction? What would be a better approach to get a bound? Finally, I did not manage to show that $|X -X_0|$ is greater than zero. I don't see how I could show this.

Thx for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you showed is $|f(X) - L| < \epsilon \implies |X -X_0| < \frac{\epsilon}{4}$.

What you need to show is $0 < |X -X_0| <\delta \implies |f(X) - L| < \epsilon$.

> The part about $0 < |X -X_0|$ is there because the value of the limit of $f(X)$ as $X$ approaches $X_0$ needs to have nothing to do with the actual value of $f(X_0)$. In, fact $f(X_0)$ does not even need to exists. For example, if you define $$f(x) = \begin{cases} 10000 & \text{If $x=7$} \\ x & \text{If $x\ne 7$} \end{cases}$$ then $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 7} f(x) = 7$. In your case, $f(X)$ is "well-behaved" at $X = X_0$ so you don't need to worry about the case $X=X_0$.

Your proof then would look like this.

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Define $\delta = \frac 19\epsilon$ and let $0 < |X -X_0| <\delta$

$|f(X) - f(1,2,1)|=|3(x-1)+4(y-2)+(z-1)| \le 3|x-1| + 4|y-2|+|z-1|$

Note that 
\begin{array}{l}
   |x-1| \le |X-(1,2,1)| < \delta \\
   |y-2| \le |X-(1,2,1)| < \delta \\
   |z-1| \le |X-(1,2,1)| < \delta \\
\end{array}

So $|f(X) - f(1,2,1)| \le 3\delta + 4\delta + \delta < 9\delta = \epsilon$

It follows that $\lim_{X\to X_0} f(X) = f(X_0)$

Answer (score 1):

Subtract $10$ both sides, 
$$ |f(\mathbf{X}) - 10 | = |3x+4y+z - 12 | =  |3(x-1)+4(y-2)+(z-1)| $$ Then by the triangle inequality $$ |f(\mathbf{X}) - 10 | \leq  3|(x-1)|+4|y-2|+|z-1| $$
Now, $$ |x-1| = \sqrt{(x-1)^2} \leq \sqrt{(x-1)^2 + (y-2)^2+(z-1)^2} = \lVert(x-1,y-2,z-1)\rVert  $$ Similarly, $|y-2| \leq \lVert(x-1,y-2,z-1)\rVert$ and $|z-1| \leq \lVert(x-1,y-2,z-1)\rVert$

so, $$ |f(\mathbf{X}) - 10 | \leq 3\lVert(x-1,y-2,z-1)\rVert + 4\lVert(x-1,y-2,z-1)\rVert+\lVert(x-1,y-2,z-1)\rVert = 8 \lVert(x-1,y-2,z-1)\rVert$$
This implies that $|f(\mathbf{X}) - 10 | < \epsilon$ if $\lVert(x-1,y-2,z-1)\rVert < \frac{\epsilon}{8}$

If you now choose $\delta = \frac{\epsilon}{8}$ then for all $(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3$  $$\text{if}\hspace{5pt} 0 < \lVert(x,y,z)-(1,2,1)\rVert < \delta \hspace{5pt} \text{then} \hspace{5pt} |f(\mathbf{X})-10 | < \epsilon  $$

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed you are correct.

$|X-X_0|=\sqrt{(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2+(z-z_0)^2}$

For the last question note that $|.|$  is the usual norm of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and from the norm's property we have that

$$|X-Y|=0 \Leftrightarrow X=Y$$

And in the definition of limit you require $X_0$ to be an accumulation point.

A point $x_0 \in  \mathbb{R}^3$ is an accumulation point  of a set $A$ iff for every $\delta>0$

($B(x_0, \delta)$ \ $\{x_0\}) \cap A \neq \emptyset$

So you have to have points which are close to $X_0$ but not equal to $X_0$.